# gspreadライブラリのworksheet()実行時に生じたエラーが解決できません。

Tags: python, google-api, google-spreadsheet, google-colaboratory

閲覧いただきありがとうございます。

### エラーが生じた経緯

google colaboratory上で作成し動作確認をしたコードをローカル環境の仮想マシン上で実行したところ、タイトルのとおりエラーが生じてしまいました。

### やりたいこと

PythonスクリプトからGoogle Sheets APIを利用しスプレッドシートにアクセスする

SheetsAPIを利用する上で同時に必要となるGoogle DriveのAPIも利用しています。
SheetsAPIの認証にはサービスアカウントキーを利用し、秘密鍵のjsonファイルを.pyファイルと同じディレクトリに配置しております。
スプレッドシート側において共有設定も済ませています。

### ローカルの実行環境

Windowsマシン上にVagrantで構築したCentOS
Python 3.5.2

### 問題のコード writeToSheets.py

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json
import pandas as pd

SP_CREDENTIAL_FILE = 'pittustatsroyale-a37bcb54c774.json'
SP_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'
]
SP_SHEET_KEY = '1_zyQWw_Kwn1nhLfsjHlm2baxH9CUweqPo6kZ38dcwo4'
SP_SHEET = 'pittu'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SP_CREDENTIAL_FILE,SP_SCOPE)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
workbook = gc.open_by_key(SP_SHEET_KEY)
worksheet = workbook.worksheet(SP_SHEET)
data = worksheet.get_all_values()
```

### 実行時のエラーメッセージ

```
[vagrant@localhost pittuStatsRoyale]$ python writeToSheets.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writeToSheets.py", line 17, in <module>
    worksheet = workbook.worksheet(SP_SHEET)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 314, in worksheet
    sheet_data = self.fetch_sheet_metadata()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 263, in fetch_sheet_metadata
    r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 67, in request
    headers=headers
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 442, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 124, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 334, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(request, self._token_uri, assertion)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 153, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 124, in _token_endpoint_request
    _handle_error_response(response_body)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.', '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."}')
```

### 試したこと

ファイルのパスなど、環境の移行に応じてコード内で変更が必要な箇所はできる限り精査しました。
16行目までは正常に実行できていると確認しましたので、スプレッドシートにはアクセスできていますが、具体的なシートを選択する段階で問題が生じているのではないかと原因を調査しました。

### 分からないこと

・Google Colaboratoryとローカル開発環境の違い。前者で実行できたコードを後者の環境で実行する場合に必要となる変更事項はあるか。

・gspreadライブラリを利用している場合において、worksheet()呼び出しに起因するエラーが生じた場合、どのようなケースが存在するのか。

### コードの作成において参考にしたもの

・Colab上での実行で参考にした動画
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBy7F4Wd9cE

・ローカルでの実行で参考にしたサイト
https://tanuhack.com/operate-spreadsheet/#i-6
https://tanuhack.com/library-gspread/#i-2

### 助力いただけますよう、よろしくお願いいたします

初めてこちらで質問させていただきました。至らぬ点ございましたらご不便をかけします。ご指摘いただけたら幸いです。何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージ末尾に

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a 
short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp 
values in the JWT claim.', '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: 
Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes)
```

とあるように
仮想マシンCentOS上の時刻設定が現時刻よりも遅れてズレていることが原因でした。
CentOSのコマンドライン上でnpt関連の設定を行うことで解消しました。

Answer (score 0):

改めて……

SP_SCOPE の順番を入れ替えて

```
SP_SCOPE = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
```

としたらどうでしょうか？

エラーの出ている部分とは違うのですが、私自身のテストコード、[公式ドキュメント](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account)、参考にされたリンクを見ても、そこくらいしか違いが見当りませんでした。

Comment: ご教授頂いたとおりに変更してみましたが、同じエラーが出ているようです。コードの変数名が分かりづらく申し訳ございません。スプレッドシートキーとワークシート名はそれぞれ上記コード中のSP_SHEET_KEYとSP_SHEETで管理してあります。助力いただき本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: スプレッドシートキーというものがあるのですね。普通のワークシートを参照する話と勘違いしました。

Comment: 一応、こちらのテストコードでは `open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_KEY)` の方でも動きましたね。

Comment: @MasahitoYasuda 改めて回答を書き直しました。

Comment: ご指摘どおり試させていただいても状況は変わらず、自分も試行錯誤したところ、エラーメッセージ末尾のToken must be a short-lived token (60 minutes)とあったので調べましたらCentOSの時刻が2時間ほど遅れていたことによるトークンの失効が原因でした。テストコードまで用意してしらみ潰しに調査してくださいまして、hataさん本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @MasahitoYasuda ともかく解決したようで何よりです。一応、ご自身の回答をAcceptして、このQ&A全体を解決済として閉じておいてください。